# JQ На динамическом коде не могу найти родительский элемент

Tags: jquery

Вот шаблон:

```
<div class="food__item item-food">
    <div class="item-food__img"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    <h2 class="item-food__title"></h2>
    <p class="item-food__text"></p>
    <div class="item-food__cost cost-item-food" data-id="">
        <div class="cost-item-food__price"></div>
        <a href="#" class="cost-item-food__btn">Купить</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Подгружаю массив с данными, заполняю шаблон для 1-го товара, вставляю в список, заполняю/вставляю...
Событие на кнопку "Купить" висит на статичном родителе, срабатывает.
Пытался добраться до "data-id" родителя кнопки "Купить". Пробовал .parent(), .parents(), .closest(), .prev().parent() в разных комбинациях, с селекторами и без них.
Не получается. Переносить data-id или менять шаблон - не вариант.
Где я ошибаюсь? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, как вы добирались до data-id

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: $('.food').on('click', '.cost-item-food__btn', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log($(this).parent().attr('data-id'));  // тут всякие комбинации перепробовал
});

Comment: Необходимо получить атрибут 'data-id' родителя кнопки.

Comment: Что ж. Пришлось сменить вёрстку. Проблема решена.